# CloudFront distribution can't access S3 bucket for website static assets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

This question follow [a previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75212166/cloudformation-template-s3-bucket-website-with-cloudfront-distribution-distr/75212251?noredirect=1#comment132720732_75212251), i decided to close that since the code changed a bit and the question did not reflect my actual situation any more.

##### The problem

I'm trying to deploy an S3 bucket hosting my static website asset and a cloudfront distribution to access it, but the distribution still return a bare csv file for an 'access denied' error:

[image]

As [this docs page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-oac-permission-to-access-s3) states in the blue Notice alert, I've not made the bucket a website endpoint, this way I can use an OAC to restrict access to its content.

A strange thing is that checking the distribution origin from the web console I see this blue alert, but the copyable policy is the same I found in the bucket permission at the given link.

[image]

I have no error during deploy, so it must be a silly configuration error, but it keeps giving me headaches since a week now and I can't figure out what is wrong.

##### Bucket and object owners corresponds

Since mi website assets are uploaded to the bucket from a different project/pipeline i followed [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-website-cloudfront-error-403/?nc1=h_ls) guide to check if the bucket and the object owners were different but actually corresponds:

```
> aws s3api list-buckets --query Owner.ID
"3fdbd1e5cad4dd2bbf4c66a3dbaded6b888fdb67ff6aa6e66203a4107fe17b72"
> aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-test-bucket --prefix index.html
{
    "Contents": [
        {
            "Key": "index.html",
            "LastModified": "2023-01-20T11:05:38+00:00",
            "ETag": "\"52f2df5ddf8c35391f3f15a7614def58\"",
            "Size": 325,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "Owner": {
                "ID": "3fdbd1e5cad4dd2bbf4c66a3dbaded6b888fdb67ff6aa6e66203a4107fe17b72"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### CloudFormation template

```yaml
Resources:

  BucketPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    DependsOn:
      - AppBucket
      - CloudFrontDistribution
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref AppBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: MyPolicy
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          Sid: PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent
          Action: s3:GetObject
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: cloudfront.amazonaws.com
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              AWS:SourceArn: !Sub arn:aws:cloudfront::${AWS::AccountId}:distribution/${CloudFrontDistribution}
          Resource: !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${AppBucket}/*

  CloudFrontDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    DependsOn:
      - AppBucket
      - DefaultCachePolicy
      - DistributionOAC
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Enabled: true
        Origins:
          - Id: AppBucket
            DomainName: !GetAtt AppBucket.DomainName
            OriginPath: /*
            S3OriginConfig: {}
            OriginAccessControlId: !Ref DistributionOAC
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
          TargetOriginId: AppBucket
          CachePolicyId: !Ref DefaultCachePolicy

  DistributionOAC:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::OriginAccessControl
    Properties: 
      OriginAccessControlConfig: 
          Name: ExampleOAC
          OriginAccessControlOriginType: s3
          SigningBehavior: always
          SigningProtocol: sigv4

  AppBucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: 'test-spa-stack-bucket-app'
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls : false
        BlockPublicPolicy : false
        IgnorePublicAcls : false
        RestrictPublicBuckets : false
              
  DefaultCachePolicy:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CachePolicy
    Properties: 
      CachePolicyConfig: 
        Name: test-cache-policy
        DefaultTTL: 10
        MaxTTL: 10
        MinTTL: 1
        ParametersInCacheKeyAndForwardedToOrigin: 
            CookiesConfig: 
              CookieBehavior: none
            EnableAcceptEncodingBrotli: true
            EnableAcceptEncodingGzip: true
            HeadersConfig: 
              HeaderBehavior: none
            QueryStringsConfig: 
              QueryStringBehavior: none
```

Comment: What's the url that gives you the 'access denied' error? Are you sure that the object that the url pointed to exists?

Comment: @jellycsc i'm browsing the distribution domain name, e.g. `d2x5xjlexample.cloudfront.net`, and i'm quite sure the destination is correct since from web console i have no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SS707jG4yZ8) that worked from cloud console, then I replicated it via CloudFormation stack template.

I think that my problem could be caused from either of these configurations:

- bucket encription: I read somewhere (sorry I can't find the exact page) that CloudFront distribution cannot (directly) read bucket objects if encripted with anything different from SSE-S3, and since I omitted that configuration it probably did fallback on a non-compatible configuration
- objects ownership: here too I forgot to add the `cuket owner enforced` policy
- distribution accepted http version: here I accepted v.2

##### working template

```yaml
Resources:
  BucketPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    DependsOn:
      - AppBucket
      - CloudFrontDistribution
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref AppBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent
        Version: '2008-10-17'
        Statement:
          Sid: AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal
          Action: s3:GetObject
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: cloudfront.amazonaws.com
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              AWS:SourceArn: !Sub arn:aws:cloudfront::${AWS::AccountId}:distribution/${CloudFrontDistribution}
          Resource: !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${AppBucket}/*

  CloudFrontDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    DependsOn:
      - AppBucket
      - DistributionOAC
      - LogsBucket
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Enabled: true
        HttpVersion: http2
        Origins:
          - Id: AppBucket
            DomainName: !GetAtt AppBucket.DomainName
            S3OriginConfig: {}
            OriginAccessControlId: !Ref DistributionOAC
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          Compress: true
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
          TargetOriginId: AppBucket
          CachePolicyId: 658327ea-f89d-4fab-a63d-7e88639e58f6   # default CachingOptimized
        Logging:
          Bucket: !GetAtt LogsBucket.DomainName
          IncludeCookies: true
          Prefix: distribution/

  AppBucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    DependsOn:
      - LogsBucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: 'test-spa-stack-bucket-app'
      OwnershipControls:
        Rules:
          - ObjectOwnership: BucketOwnerEnforced
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls : true
        BlockPublicPolicy : true
        IgnorePublicAcls : true
        RestrictPublicBuckets : true
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256
      LoggingConfiguration:
        DestinationBucketName: !Ref LogsBucket
        LogFilePrefix: app/

  DistributionOAC:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::OriginAccessControl
    Properties: 
      OriginAccessControlConfig: 
          Name: test-spa-distribution-oac
          OriginAccessControlOriginType: s3
          SigningBehavior: always
          SigningProtocol: sigv4


  LogsBucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: 'test-spa-stack-bucket-logs'
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls : true
        BlockPublicPolicy : true
        IgnorePublicAcls : true
        RestrictPublicBuckets : true
      AccessControl: LogDeliveryWrite
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
        - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
            SSEAlgorithm: 'AES256'
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't to have much luck without using legacy OAI (for no reason).
So, here's a policy you can use for target S3 bucket after you create the OAI right there in Cloudfront:

```
    {
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity INSERT_OAI_NUMBER_HERE"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME_HERE/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

After you do that, it should return expected content.
If it does work for you and you start asking why, you'd better find something better to do.